# RunAsUser issue with postgres

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, okd

I have encountered error when I am running the postgreSQL in OKD.

The error message I encountered is: `Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I have customized the pg_hba.conf file and this is the configuration I put for the local connection:
`local  postgres    all peer`

As per some security, I am required to put it as peer authentication.

In the statefulset.yaml file, I am required to configure the RunAsUser and RunAsGroup securityContext, and here is how I did it

```
spec:
    securityContext: 
        runAsUser: 10001
        runAsGroup: 10001
        fsGroup: 10001
    serviceAccountName: ...
    containers:
    - name: db
    image: ....
    volumeMounts:
        - name: data
        mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    securityContext:
        seccompProfile: 
            type: RuntimeDefault
        runAsNonRoot: true
```

Comment: "peer" authentication only works for connections over the local (unix) socket. It is not available for network connections and is unlikely to work in this situation.

Comment: Previously I have tested that peer works and the postgresql is able to startup properly without the error, but after I put the runAsUser in the helm charts then the postgresql hits with the error message of peer authentication failed for user postgres. I think I don't understand why is the error about, will you please guide? Thank you so much

Comment: The error message peer authentication failed for user postgres, happens when I put the runAsUser in the helm chart and invoked the helm install, and after the helm install, the postgresql is unable to startup and the error I peer authentication failed for user postgres. Sorry if I didn't explain  properly